# How to complete the square of this surface so that we can identify the type of surface?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, surfaces

Equation of surface
$$5x_1^2+2x_2^2+2x_3^2-{4x_1 x_2}-{4x_1 x_3}-{8x_2 x_3}=7.$$

I ended up with
$$(2x_1 - x_2 - x_3)^2 + (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^2 - 2x_1 x_2 - 2x_1 x_3 - 8x_2 x_3 = 7$$
but don't know how to proceed. Would be highly apppreciated if you could complete the square for this equation so that I can see if the eigenvalues are positive or not. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: (Thanks, @Will Jagy, for cleaning up the notation! Whew! :)

Comment: @paulgarrett  you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this with symmetric matrices. The first thing I did was to switch $x_1$ and $x_2.$   Let me take a minute to show just that much in matrices...

Note that I change one $\pm$ sign to keep $\det P = 1$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
 - 4 & 2 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
 - 4 & 2 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

From this point it became easy

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 18 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 18 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

The outcome, as formulas, is  that your form (in variables $x,y,z$) comes out
$$ \color{blue}{2(-x+y-2z)^2 + 3 (-x+2z)^2 -18 z^2} $$

If you do the thing purely algorithmically you must expect  fractions...

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  \\ 
 - 2 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 18 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 18 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  - 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 18 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 4 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Wow, I am speechless. That must have taken some time! Thank you.